# New-AzureStorageAccount PowerShell command never returns

Tags: powershell, azure

I am trying to create a new Azure storage account using the following command:

```
PS> New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName 'newstoragerobower' -Location 'West US' -Description 'Test account for automation VMs' -Label 'AutomationStorageAccount'
```

However, it never returns. It successfully creates the storage account (verified through Azure Management Console). I can get it to return using a workaround where I start it as a job, then call Wait-Job with a timeout, thusly:

```
PS> $job = Start-Job -Name myName -Command { $storageAcct = New-AzureStorageAccount -StorageAccountName 'newstoragerobower' -Location 'West US' -Description 'Test account for automation VMs' -Label 'AutomationStorageAccount' }
PS> Wait-Job $job -Timeout 20
```

At best, this will add significant unnecessary delay to my scripts, and at worst it could cause the job to abort mid-execution (sometimes Azure jobs take longer then usual). Does anyone know why the command is not returning normally?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try running with the -Debug option, or setting $DebugPreference to Continue?  This isn't generally the case for creating storage accounts, would like to understand what's different about yur subscription that is producing this issue.